# Any visual diff in Linux console?

Tags: diff

Many years ago I used [d32](https://web.archive.org/web/20090207074101/http://www.openetwork.com/delta.html) which was available for [DOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS) and Linux.

Is a non-GUI visual diff available for Linux like this one?

Any others than [Vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29) and Emacs (Vim and Emacs are too powerful :-) )

Comment: Maybe move this to softwarerecommendations.SX ?

Comment: The question is close but I need to add: If you like the `vimdiff` option but are a neovim user: use `nvim -d` respectively (`alias diff = 'nvim -d'`). You're welcome.

Comment: See here to answer this question instead, if you'd like to add a new answer: https://superuser.com/questions/92153/interactive-visual-merge-tool-for-console.

Answer (score 77):

I'm using `vimdiff`. Or there is also `sdiff`.

Comment: sdiff seems nice, but is there any variation of it that supports coloured output?

Comment: note: Vim comes with vimdiff already

Answer (score 39):

If you're comfortable with `git`, you can also use [`git diff`](http://www.kernel.org/pub//software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html) to generate a patch for you. It'll usually give you nice colors, page to `less`, and output the [unified diff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Unified_format) format by default. It'll work regardless of whether the files are part of a git repository.

```
git diff -- file.a file.b
```

If `file.a` and `file.b` reside in a git repo and are untracked, you'll need to supply `--no-index`:

```
git diff --no-index -- file.a file.b
```

because git will diff against the index by default.

Comment: `git diff --no-index` works great! I had no idea the `--no-index` option was there. I used to always type out the full `diff -u --color=always file1.txt file2.txt`, which has **identical** output to `git diff`. That being said, `git diff` output is pretty horrible to look at, hence why `meld` was born. I'll keep this in my toolshed but keep looking for a more meld-like, but ncurses-based, tool.

Comment: Using option `--color-words` highlights more nicely inline changes. But my preferred option is `--color-words='[[:alnum:]]+|[^[:space:]]'`. Really great option to have in gitconfig (together with --no-index)

Answer (score 27):

None of the existing answers here quite fit my use case, but I found [cdiff](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cdiff), which is a lovely little piece of software that does exactly what I need:

> Term based tool to view colored, incremental diff in a Git/Mercurial/Svn workspace or from stdin, with side by side and auto pager support.

Here's what the side by side mode looks like:

[image: side by side diff output]

Comment: it [seems](https://github.com/ymattw/cdiff/issues/61) it is only for parsing VCS output

Comment: It handles the display of standard diff formats. It does not generate the diff itself - you can do that using `diff -u one.txt two.txt | cdiff`

Comment: I found cdiff -s -w 0 in this case works pretty well.  Thanks for pointing us to cdiff.

Comment: There is also an "improve cdiff" that people may find useful: https://github.com/jeffkaufman/icdiff

Comment: Hallelujah!!!!!

Comment: This program (`cdiff`) is now called `ydiff` (due to a naming conflict with `cdiff` I presume), and is available here: https://github.com/ymattw/ydiff.

Answer (score 19):

You can try [ColorDiff](http://colordiff.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Works well but color output is lost when piping through `less`. Use `less -r` to keep the colors.

Answer (score 10):

[Vim](http://vim.org) comes with [vimdiff](http://amjith.blogspot.com/2008/08/quick-and-dirty-vimdiff-tutorial.html) which works pretty well...

Answer (score 5):

Midnight Commander (mc) has built-in diff and a lot more useful functions. Try:

> sudo apt install mc

Answer (score 4):

Personally I like to use vimdiff. But if you don't know vim that won't be that helpful to you.

Comment: There aren't too many vim-specific tricks to using `vimdiff` (except remembering how to exit.)  One tip is that you can specify the `-o` switch to make it use horizontal windows instead of the default vertical (`-O`.)

Answer (score 3):

Your title mentions "Linux console" but your question mentions `meld`, which is a GUI application. It might help answerers if you could clarify this.

In GUI apps, meld is still pretty much the standard. It works well, it's reasonably pretty and intuitive.

If you're really limited to using the console (i.e. text-only) then apart from the diff utilities built into editors like `vim` and `emacs` you could also try the original command line utility `diff`. I find it very useful to use the `-y` option to display files side-by-side, and there are other options I've used to display "unified" diffs and to precisely set the amount of context around matched differences. If you pipe diff's output into `less` you can browse with fair convenience.

Comment: Thanks Cral, the problem is not relate to limited to using the console,I'm prefer using console mode :-)

Answer (score 2):

vimdiff will do what you want.  Vim is installed by default on most linux distros, so you probably do not even need to install anything.

Answer (score 2):

[Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) has a built-in visual diff tool: `M-x ediff`.

Comment: Did you read the full question?

Comment: Yes, but if you look at the question's edit history, you will notice that the part about "not Vim or Emacs" was done **after** I wrote my answer. :)

Comment: Too bad I couldn't do M-x vc-diff on that. Peace :)

Comment: No probs. Had to do some digging myself to realize why it seemed like I hadn't read the question. :)

Answer (score 1):

I started to rebuild xxdiff in the console (since I've entirely switched to tmux console development) into a new Python-based single-file tool I call "termdiff". I ran into curses compatibility problems so I put this on the ice for now, I just need some time to fix minor issues with filling empty space, but it currently spits out output that looks just like xxdiff and you can pipe that into less.

http://furius.ca/xxdiff/bin/termdiff

Try termdiff --cat or termdiff --less, it works.

In the meantime I'm using a customized Emacs config and ediff, but it's a little sluggish to start, I'd still like a fast-startup dedicated diff program in the console.

Answer (score -2):

Try [meld](http://meldmerge.org/). It's very light and intuitive.

Comment: `meld` is a GUI; they are looking for a Linux console-based application, likely ncurses-based so it will be GUI-like, interactive, and intuitive. Note, if you want to see what an ncurses application looks and feels like, run `htop` or `ncdu`. They are both terminal-based but based on ncurses, which makes them GUI-like and fairly intuitive.